# How do I get rid of this problem blocked by CORS policy (with java spring boot)?

Tags: java, typescript, spring-boot, cors, vercel

I'm having problems with cors with my spring java API, I deployed it to render but when I try to consume it it gives a CORS error even though I passed the domain from my frontend to the backend to allow access.

application.properties

```
cors.origins=${CORS_ORIGINS:https://ds-commerce-v1.netlify.app}
```

the error:
(ds-commerce-v1.netlify.app/:1 Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'https://api-dsecommerce.onrender.com/products?page=0&name=&size=12&sort=name' from origin 'https://ds-commerce-v1.netlify.app' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.*

I passed the environment variables in the frontend deploy to match my api address but it seems like something is wrong and it is not accepting the req at that frontend address.

This is the code for CORS in my api but idkn where the problem is

```
@Configuration
@EnableResourceServer
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true)
public class ResourceServerConfig extends ResourceServerConfigurerAdapter {

    @Value("${cors.origins}")
    private String corsOrigins;
    
    @Autowired
    private Environment env;
    
    @Autowired
    private JwtTokenStore tokenStore;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(ResourceServerSecurityConfigurer resources) throws Exception {
        resources.tokenStore(tokenStore);
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {

        // H2
        if (Arrays.asList(env.getActiveProfiles()).contains("test")) {
            http.headers().frameOptions().disable();
        }
        
        http.authorizeRequests().anyRequest().permitAll();
        
        http.cors().configurationSource(corsConfigurationSource());
    }
    
    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {

        String[] origins = corsOrigins.split(",");

        CorsConfiguration corsConfig = new CorsConfiguration();
        corsConfig.setAllowedOriginPatterns(Arrays.asList(origins));
        corsConfig.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("POST", "GET", "PUT", "DELETE", "PATCH"));
        corsConfig.setAllowCredentials(true);
        corsConfig.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization", "Content-Type"));
     
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", corsConfig);
        return source;
    }

    @Bean
    FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> corsFilter() {
        FilterRegistrationBean<CorsFilter> bean
                = new FilterRegistrationBean<>(new CorsFilter(corsConfigurationSource()));
        bean.setOrder(Ordered.HIGHEST_PRECEDENCE);
        return bean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question? https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question

Comment: Did you use @CrossOrigin(origins = { "*" }) as controller class  annotation?